# pexpect asyncio generator results

Tags: python-asyncio, pexpect

I have a script which produces a asyncio generator object from pexpect. I am not able to figure out how to parse this generator to actually display the results (the output of the ping command). My code is as below

```
try:
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server1')
    child.expect('Password:')
    child.sendline('xxxxxxx')
    child.expect('.*>')
    cmd='ping -c4 vm1'
    child.sendline(cmd)
    index = child.expect('.*>', async=True)
    child.sendline('exit')
    print (index)
except:
    print('Exception')
    child.sendline('exit')
```

This displays the generator object as

```
<generator object expect_async at 0x2ad79cc47258>
```

I am new to this async concept with pexpect, so trying to figure out a way to parse this generator to display actual output.
This has to run in async as part of some specific project requirements. Kindly suggest.

## Updated Code

```
import pexpect, asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def test_ssh_expect_async():
    try:
        child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server1')
        child.expect('Password:')
        child.sendline('xxxxx')
        child.expect('.*>')
        cmd='ping -c5 vm1'
        child.sendline(cmd)
        yield from child.expect('.*>', async=True)
        child.sendline('exit')
    except:
        print('Exception')
        child.sendline('exit')

@asyncio.coroutine
def test_loop():
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(test_ssh_expect_async())
    yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print('All Tasks done')


print('--------------Async--------------------')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_loop())
```

Comment: Have you tried `await`ing the coroutine returned by `.expect`? The [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) suggests using `yield from`. Have you done that?

Comment: I have been through the document. However, I am not able to figure out a proper way to handle this. There are bits and pieces of information but not exactly what i am looking for...

Comment: Can you provide a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? This code you showed is not complete and not really minimal. Surely this is inside some function, right?

Comment: The updated code is here in the question description. However, still not sure how to get the ping command output

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In general, I would suggest always including version information in your question from the very beginning. This includes the Python version you are using and the versions of any third-party packages involved.

Comment: Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 13 2020, 07:46:32)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: Instead of applying the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator, just make your functions [`async`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0492/#new-coroutine-declaration-syntax). Then use `await child.expect(..., async_=True)` and `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` (or use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)). I would also advise calling the main coroutine function via [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) rather than `loop.run_until_complete`.

Comment: I have tried this approach. However, there seems to be a conflict because of the pexpect child object in the await call. Looking for some other options at the moment....